# How do you get HDR tiff files from Photomatix/HDR Efex Pro to show up in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom

I've used both Photomatrix Pro and HDR Efex Pro to make HDR images from Lightroom. In Lightroom I select the exposures, right click and choose "Export to XXX" where XXX is Photomatrix Pro or HDR Efex Pro. Lightroom proceeds to make a bunch of tif files then launch the selected plugin. I edit in the plugin and pick save but the new tif file does not show up at the bottom of Lightroom where all the images are (the Filmstrip). How do I get the tiff files to show up?

Note: If I go back Library and click on a folder I see them but I want to seem them in the Filmstrip (or what the area under the current photo is called)

[image]

Comment: I just synchronize the folder again after working with the external editor. Works fine for me, but obviously is not the most seamless either.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not in a collection, the HDR image *will* show up in the filmstrip.  In the screenshot along with your question, I can see that you're in the "Previous Import" collection.

Because the resulting HDR image was not part of the previous import, it's not in that collection.

If you were viewing the "All Photographs" grouping, you'd see the HDR image appear in the filmstrip.

Comment: Ahh the "Previous Import" I do this far too often, scan back and forth through the images -- oops. LR needs to have an on import option to go to the folder (if there was only one) automatically for slow folks like me.

Answer (score 0):

After you close Photomatix / HDR Efex go to the Library tab and click "All Photographs".

Also make sure that the option to **"Automatically Re-Import into Lightroom LIbrary"** is enabled in Photomatix. (I think there might be a similar setting in HDR Efex Pro)

There is also an **option to stack photos**. Personally I very much dislike the stacking function so I **uncheck it**.  If you stack - your HDR might be stacked with the source photos in your filmstrip so not visible until you unstack.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you send the photos to HDR Effex Pro from Lightroom through the "Edit in" control panel option it will not send it back to Lightroom when finished.  However, if you choose "Export" and choose HDR Effex Pro it WILL send the picture back to Lightroom.  I was tearing my hair out trying to figure this out and realized I was not exporting but choosing Edit in.